# Is there a difference between "areNotificationsEnabled()" and "checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)"

Tags: android, notifications, android-13

Google says that all apps targeting Android 13 (API level 33) in order to be able to work with notifications must ask for **Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS** permission.

My question is: which is a proper way to check if that permission is already granted?

1. using `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()`
2. using somthing like `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)`

Are there any differences between them? It seems like these two options depend on each other: for example, if I go to the device app settings and disable Notifications then I see that Notification permission is also automatically revoked from the app:

[image]

[image]

and vice versa.

Answer (score 8):

The both mentioned ways of checking permissions:
`NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()`

and

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`

returns exactly the same result in all three options in case of:

- granted permission (true)
- denied permission (false)
- forever denied permission (false)

So there are no differences between them, and you can choose the option that you prefer more.

- The first one is a more concise way and you don't have to surround your code with the `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33)` check
- The second option is a more general one. Also, used for asking about other permissions, so you can create an extension function for it to make this option easier to use. For example:

```
private fun Context.permissionGranted(permission: String): Boolean =
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Unfortunately, with the second option you still have to surround your code with the SDK check, so it would look like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) permissionGranted(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
```

And also, at the end, some general info about the notifications and the app settings:

- Yes, the permission and the notification options depends on each other
- The notifications are by default turned off staring from Android 13 (SDK 33)
- After clearing the app data all permissions are cleared, also the notification one.

Answer (score 4):

> returns exactly the same result in all three options

Apparently not on all devices. I consistently got PERMISSION_DENIED, despite permissions being enabled in the settings, when using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`.

Changing to `NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()` matches up to settings.

Might be the Samsung android version that isn't set up correctly or something, but NotificationManagerCompat seems like the safer choice.

Comment: `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` has fallback to the `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` if the Android < 13, otherwise a permission check is performed by process id and user id

Comment: May I know, what is the correct way to handle siutation when `NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()` is false? Is requesting runtime permission POST_NOTIFICATIONS the right step?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng That depends on what API level you are. The `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission does not exist prior to API Level 33.  So on API levels < 33 you can only request the user to enable notifications for your app in the settings. You may even redirect the user to that settings screen with the correct intent. On API Level >= 33 it really doesn't matter whether you request permisson or a settings update: Enabling the setting should automatically grant permission and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

On systems before Android 13 (API level 33), the compat version of the `checkSelfPermission(this, POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` function delegates to the compat version of the `areNotificationsEnabled()` function.

So looking at the AOSP sources for the [`NotificationManagerService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-13.0.0_r83/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#7087) you'll notice that the call to `areNotificationsEnabled()` eventually delegates to `mPermissionHelper.hasPermission(uid)`

```
/**
 * Returns whether the given uid holds the notification permission. Must not be called
 * with a lock held.
 */
public boolean hasPermission(int uid) {
    final long callingId = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        return mPmi.checkUidPermission(uid, NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(callingId);
    }
}
```

So I'd say it's safe to assume that the `areNotificationsEnabled()` function and the more generic call to the `checkSelfPermission(this, POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` function could be considered equivalent.