# When requesting for POST_NOTIFICATIONS, shuold we check for Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS or areNotificationsEnabled?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Since Android 13, we need to request the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission before we are able to send notifications.

However, how can we decide whether a request for the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission is necessary?

Should we check for

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Or, should we check for

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

In all my test cases, I found that `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` and `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()` always return the same value.

Is this behavior guaranteed? If not, in what kind of situation will they return different values?

There is a similar discussion on this issue : [Is there a difference between "areNotificationsEnabled()" and "checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671885/is-there-a-difference-between-arenotificationsenabled-and-checkselfpermissi)

However, there is no authorized documentation source being provided.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are permissions but "NotificationEnabled" is a different thing.
Before be able to Post a Notification you have to ASK user for permissions, but after this the user could disable ALL Notifications (not its Permissions that remains Enabled) for your package/App.
You can check this difference by going to your App Info Page and you'll see that there is a "Notification" under "Permissions" and a "Notification"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code from Jetpack and the AOSP, both variants should be equivalent.

On Android devices pre Android 13, `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` delegates to `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()`.

[On Android 13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-13.0.0_r83/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#7087) and maybe later, `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()` uses the platform implementation eventually checking the permission as well.

But always keep in mind that device manufacturers might change the implementation for their devices.